# Split Integer List in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of integers. I want to split the main list into multiple sub lists of non-zero integers.

Example:

```
main_lists = [0,0,0,0,0,0,123,432,5,54,0,654,645,34,23,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,123,1,312,312,132,3,123,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

output = 

[123,432,5,54,0,654,645,34,23,12]
[123,1,312,312,132,3,123]
```

Condition is,
If one or two (less than < 5) zero is found in between two non zero values, then it should include those zeros int out put lists. If more that 5  consecutive zero is found then it should split the list from that position.

```
main_lists = [0,0,0,0,0,0,123,432,5,54,0,654,645,34,23,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,123,1,312,312,132,3,123,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
zero_count = 0
non_zero_temp = []
for i in main_lists:
    if i == 0:
        zero_count = zero_count + 1
    else:
        if zero_count < 5:
            non_zero_temp.append(i)
            zero_count = 0
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Something like this : 

main_lists = [0,0,0,0,0,0,123,432,5,54,0,654,645,34,23,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,123,1,312,312,132,3,123,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
zero_count = 0
non_zero_temp = []
for i in main_lists:
 if i = 0:
  zero_count = zero_count + 1
 else:
  if zero_count < 5:
   non_zero_temp.append(i)
   zero_cout = 0

Comment: @Ffisegydd done! thnx

Comment: Is this not exactly the same as [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970686/derive-sub-list-from-a-long-list-depending-in-value)?

Comment: @Ffisegydd not actually,,I went wrong in that question..Is there anything i can do about that...delete the question or mark that as irrelevant ?? sorry for that..

Comment: _"I went wrong in that question."_ What do you mean by that? If possible, try to correct the question by editing it.

Comment: Un-intentionally i made the prob. more complex in that question.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post an alternative:

```
output = []
non_zero_temp = []
length = len(main_lists)
i = 0
while i < length:
    zeros = []
    while i < length and main_lists[i] == 0:
        i += 1
        zeros.append(0)
    if len(zeros) != 0 and len(zeros) < 5:
        non_zero_temp += zeros
    elif len(zeros) > 5:
        if len(non_zero_temp) > 0 and i < length:
            output.append(non_zero_temp)
            non_zero_temp = []
    else:
        non_zero_temp.append(main_lists[i])
        i += 1
if len(non_zero_temp) > 0:
    output.append(non_zero_temp)
print(output)

[[123, 432, 5, 54, 0, 654, 645, 34, 23, 12], [123, 1, 312, 312, 132, 3, 123]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby

main_lists = [
    0,0,0,0,0,0,123,432,5,54,0,654,645,34,23,12,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,123,1,312,312,132,3,123,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
]

# group numbers into contiguous lists (by 0 or not-0)
is_zero = lambda n: not n
groups = (list(nums) for zero,nums in groupby(main_lists, key=is_zero))

# group lists into contiguous chunks (by to-keep or to-discard)
is_keeper = lambda lst: bool(lst[0]) or len(lst) < 5
chunks = (chunk for keep,chunk in groupby(grouped, key=is_keeper) if keep)

# reassemble chunks
final = [[i for lst in chunk for i in lst] for chunk in chunks]
```

results in

```
[[123, 432, 5, 54, 0, 654, 645, 34, 23, 12], [123, 1, 312, 312, 132, 3, 123]]
```

Comment: You could just use `bool` as the key in `groupby`, rather than a lambda.

Comment: @Blckknght: yes, I was using `operator.not_` but figured this was "more obvious".